# Start PowerPoint Slideshow using Microsoft.Interop

Tags: interop, slideshow, powerpoint, presentation

I'm totally new to C#. Using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint namespace, I want to be able to start a PowerPoint Presentation from code. There's a path and a finished presentation, and I want it to start in full screen automatically.

How can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Simplest thing might be to save the presentation as a PPSX then ShellExecute it.  PPS/PPSX files automatically start in full screen slide show view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using PPT = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
namespace PowerPointLauncher
{
    public void StartPresentation()
    {
        PPT.Application app = new PPT.Application();
        //optionally on SlideShowEnd close all powerpoint windows created by your application (app)
        app.SlideShowEnd += App_SlideShowEnd;
        var pres = app.Presentations.Open("d:\\test.ppt", MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

        app.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run();
    }

    private void App_SlideShowEnd(Presentation Pres)
    {
        foreach (DocumentWindow window in Pres.Application.Windows)
        {
            window.Close();
        }
    }
}
```